# use microphone in background

Tags: android, audiorecord

I want to write a list of applications that use the microphone in the background in the last hour. can it be done using state ([AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord))? or other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  There is no API to get what other applications have used a resource.

Comment: and can I follow my microphone using my application?